# How can I apply the same frame style to all the pictures of a collage at once in Picture Collage Maker Pro?

Tags: batch-processing, script, picture-collage-maker-pro

I have a collage with >20 pictures in [Picture Collage Maker Pro](https://www.pearlmountainsoft.com/picture-collage-maker) on Windows 10. How can I apply the same frame style to all the pictures of my collage at once? I don't want to have to do it for each picture manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find anything in the GUI. However, the `.pwp` project files ([Picture Collage Maker Pro](https://www.pearlmountainsoft.com/picture-collage-maker) project files) are XML files, and can be easily changed to apply the same frame style to all the pictures of a collage at once.

In a `.pwp` project file, each picture is saved as:

```
<SceneObject
    Version="3"
    Type="0"
    Image="\Page1\photo\coolpic.png"
    Angle="0"
    EnableMask="0"
    MaskName="masknull"
    EnableFrame="1"
    FrameName=""
    BorderType="0"
    ColorBorderColorR="255"
    ColorBorderColorG="255"
    ColorBorderColorB="255"
    ColorBorderWidth="2"
    ColorBorderUnit="0"
    BoundingBoxLeft="1780"
    BoundingBoxTop="1140"
    BoundingBoxRight="2443"
    BoundingBoxBottom="2336"
    PhotoRotation="0"
    Visible="1"
    Transparent="1.000000"
    CropLeft="0"
    CropTop="0"
    CropRight="332"
    CropBottom="600"
    EnableShadow="0"
    ShadowPrecise="2"
    ShadowColorR="0"
    ShadowColorG="0"
    ShadowColorB="0"
    ShadowAlpha="65"
    ShadowSmooth="5"
    ShadowOffsetX="9"
    ShadowOffsetY="9"
/>
```

As a result, one can do a "replace all" to apply the same frame style to all the pictures of a collage at once:

[image]